# How do we use "lookup" in Nodejs to include partials?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

We use this syntax to include partial during run time:

```
{{> (lookup . 'file') }}
```

**file** is a var name from the parent file.

I tried to add a prefix to the file name, So I tried:

- `{{> lookup . 'path/file'}}`
- `{{> (lookup . (strmerge 'path/' 'file')) }}`
  *Note: I made a helper method to merge strings*

I tried those and others but nothing worked for me.

Does any one know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is handlebars syntax and it works the same in Java, node.js, python, ruby, go etc

Comment: @slebetman ok how to combine path with file name and use `lookup` helper?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is `path/` a String and `file` a variable?

Comment: @76484 yes, `path/` is a string, `file` is variable passed from parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code `{{> (lookup . 'file') }}` we are telling Handlebars that the name of our partial is to be found at the `file` property of the current context object.

Assuming a context object like `{ file: 'myPartial' }`, the result of the lookup is `{{> myPartial }}`, which tells Handlebars to render a partial called "myPartial".

If we want to add a prefix to our partial, so that Handlebars will register a partial called "path/myPartial", the simplest way to do this would be to add that path to the value of the `file` property in the context object. The context object would become: `{ file: 'path/myPartial' }`.

If, for some reason, the "path/" prefix must be added to the *template* and not the *data*, then we will need to determine a way to produce the String "path/myPartial" from our current data.

Both of your attempts put "file" in the name of the property to be looked-up. Your code will try to find the property `path/file` on the context object and this will fail. We will definitely need a helper to concatenate Strings, but it must concatenate "path/" with the *value* of `file`, not the literal String, "file".

To achieve our goal we will no longer require the `lookup` helper. The `lookup` was needed only because you can't write `{{> (file) }}` in Handlebars, because Handlebars will treat `file` as a helper instead of as a variable. However, since we are using a concatenation helper, `strmerge`, we can use the String it returns as our partial name, without any need for a `lookup`. The correct code becomes:

```
{{> (strmerge 'path/' file) }}
```

It's important to note that `file` in this example is not in quotes. It is a variable, not a String.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/t0da1yyb/) for your reference.